# How do you keep authorization active when entering the docs in Fastapi?

Tags: python, authentication, swagger, jinja2, fastapi

I am using some basic oauth2 authentication in Python, fast api. I want to hide all of the swagger docs behind a login, and ideally I would want all the login logic to be handled by the oauth2scheme, such that when a user logs in to see the docs, they do not need to reauthenticate in order to test any of the endpoints.

The closest I have gotten to a solution is logging in the user by saving a cookie to the request, then overwriting the swagger ui to check the cookie and logout the user. The only functionality I am missing is having the user be automatically authenticated once entering the docs based on this cookie. Relevant code below:

```
@dbparse.get("/", include_in_schema=False, response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def login_page(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("login.html", {"request": request})
```

```
@dbparse.post("/login", include_in_schema=False)
async def perform_login(
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    username: Optional[str] = Form(None),
    password: Optional[str] = Form(None),
):
    try:
        if not (username and password):
            return RedirectResponse(
                "/?error=true", status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER
            )
        # Fake an oauth login form to route login attempts to previously written code
        form = OAuth2PasswordRequestForm(username=username, password=password, scope="")
        token = await generate_token(form)
        response = RedirectResponse("/docs", status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
        # Set the user's login cookie so that we can have them auth'd later
        response.set_cookie(
            key="Authorization",
            value=f"{token['token_type'].capitalize()} {token['access_token']}",
        )
        return response
    except:
        return RedirectResponse("/?error=true", status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
```

```
@dbparse.get("/docs", include_in_schema=False)
async def custom_swagger_ui_html(request: Request):
    if request.cookies:
        try:
            token = await generate_token(None, request.cookies)
        except:
            response = RedirectResponse("/?expired=true", status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
            response.delete_cookie(key="Authorization")
            return response
    return get_swagger_ui_html(...)
```

```
@dbparse.post("/token", include_in_schema=False)
async def generate_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), cached_token = None):
    print("==========================\nGENERATE_TOKEN()\n==========================")
    if cached_token:
        try:
            _, access_token = cached_token["Authorization"].split(" ")
            _ = decode_token(access_token)
            # Ensure that the token in cookies is working. (Confirmed to work as intended)
            return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
        except:
            raise
    user = authenticate(form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Invalid username/password",
        )
    token = create_token(user)

    return {"access_token": token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

If there is an easier solution, I was unable to find it. The key functionality I am looking for is to use a cookie to authenticate the swagger docs for endpoint use. The endpoints need to require authentication, but ideally when you log in before seeing the docs, this authentication should carry over.

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/364#issuecomment-789711477

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?? If so could you share your code? Thanks